# How to Print TMemo Text in FireMonkey

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I cannot seem to get the text of a TMemo to print. I can get it to print, but it prints 3 of the same pages. Also, how would I calculate the totalPages so that the procedure knows when to stop printing? I am not supposed to use any 3rd party components.

Here is my code

```
function PrintPage(sText:string):boolean;
var
  DestRect:TRectF;
  align:TTextAlign;
  textFill: tFillTextFlags;
  printDialog: TPrintDialog;
  totalPages : integer;
begin
  printDialog := TPrintDialog.Create(nil);
  printDialog.PrintRange := TPrintRange.prAllPages;
  textFill := [];
  align:=TTextAlign.taLeading;
  totalPages := 3;
  if printDialog.Execute() Then
  begin
    with Printer do
    begin
      ActivePrinter;
      BeginDoc;
      while Printer.Printing do
      begin
         DestRect := RectF(50,50,(Printer.Pagewidth - 50),(Printer.PageHeight - 50));
         Canvas.FillText(DestRect,sText,True,1,textFill,align,align);
         if Printer.PageNumber <> totalPages then
           Printer.NewPage
         else
           EndDoc;
       end;
     end;
     Result := not Printer.Aborted;
   end;
 end;
```

Comment: The reason why it prints thre of the same pages is becouse you update the printer canvas only once. You should update it again with context of the next page before printing that page using NewPage.

Comment: I cant figure it out. What happened to old fashioned WriteLine, ugh

Comment: Isn't the WriteLine from the DOS era? Anyway which version of Delphi do you use? I'm asking this because some older Delphi versions shipped with standard version of Quick Report. Quick Report is a component suite that allows you to visually prepare printer outputs by placing special components on the form so you see exactly how the output should look on paper. Do note that while Quick Report components are shipped with some Delphi versions they are usually not installed into the IDE by default so check online for instruction on how to install these components for your specific Delphi version

Comment: XE7.   Ill look into Quick Report

Comment: I'm afraid Quick Report is no longer shipped with Delphi XE7. So you will either have to buy it or perhaps use some other reporting components. If my memory serves me correctly the Delphi XE7 ships with Crystal Report which is much more powerfull but is implemented in a different way so you won't be able to just put some components on a form like you would do with Quick Report.